# How can I translate a 6x7 int array into a single dimension array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an array of coordiantes

```
int[][] xyBoard = new int[6][7];

int[] flattenedBoard = new int[42];
```

where 0,0 is the bottom left of the board.

I want to display the data in a grid but the grid wants to lay everything out from top left to bottom right

The grid needs a one dimensional array of length 42, position 1 in this array needs to correspond to x,y 0,5 in the xyBoard array, position 2 in the flattened array would then be 1,5 in the 2d array, etc... Any ideas on how to either translate the xyBoard into the flattened array or a formula to reference the right coordinates of the 2d array given the 1d arrays position.

Comment: Use nester `for loops` to copy data from on array to other. Simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula to reference the coordinates is

```
int idx(int x, int y) {
    return y*widthOfBoard() + x;
}

int x(int idx) {
    return idx % widthOfBoard();
}

int y(int idx) {
    return (idx - x(idx)) / widthOfBoard();
}
```

To get the index for one dimension array do call
    idx(x,y)

where x, y is your coordinate.

To get x coordinate from index do

```
x(idx)
```

where idx is your index from one dimension array.

Comment: This is close, but I dont think i was clear. The order needs to change. For example in the 1d array the first six values should correspond to (0,6)(1,6)(2,6)(3,6)(4,6)(5,6)(6,6) in the 2d array

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple loop writing all elements of 2Darray to your 1d array

```
int[][] xyBoard = new int[6][7];
int[] flattenedBoard = new int[42];

int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 6 ; ++i){

    for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j){
        flattenedBoard[sum] = xyBoard[i][j];
        sum++;
}
sum++;
}
```